# Reducir el tamaño de letra y aumentar márgenes de un plot

Tags: r

Me gustaría hacer el tamaño de letra del eje y más pequeño para este plot.
El plot es el resultado del juntar varias matrices; es decir un análisis RLQ.
Las matrices están disponibles aquí: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZZl6LItgEdJXZLLfa6yKnGSRGHWv4kJS

```
 R <- read.delim("R.txt")
 L <- read.delim("L.txt")
 Q <- read.delim("Q.txt")
```

Para ello he ejecutado el siguiente código:

```
 four.comb.aravo <- fourthcorner(R, L, Q, modeltype = 6, p.adjust.method.G = "none",p.adjust.method.D = "none", nrepet = 999).
```

Después intento plotear esta función ejecutando el código:

```
   plot(four.comb.aravo,type=c("table")
```

[image: Plot]

Este plot muestra los nombres del eje y muy juntos y me gustaría reducirles el tamaño y además me gustaría dar margen a los extremos del plot, para ello ejecuté el siguiente código

```
    par(oma=c(3,1,1,1),mfrow=c(1,3))
    plot(four.comb.aravo,type=c("table"),cex.lab=0.5)
```

No obstante no reduce el tamaño de letra ni los márgenes del plot como anteriores veces. ¿Cómo podría cambiarlos?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente, no se puede configurar lo que pides desde la función misma, a menos que el autor del paquete implemente esta funcionalidad. Si bien se pueden pasar parámetros adicionales estos no son usados en el código que se encarga de construir la tabla. Para poder hacerlo podrías intentar reescribir dos funciones de este paquete:

- [`plot.4thcorner`](https://github.com/cran/ade4/blob/master/R/plot.4thcorner.R)
- [`table.prepare`](https://github.com/cran/ade4/blob/master/R/table.value.R)

En la primer función, tienes esta llamada:

```
table.prepare(x = x1, y = y, row.labels = row.names(df), col.labels = names(df), 
              clabel.row = 1, clabel.col = 1, grid = FALSE, 
              pos = "paint")
```

Como puedes ver, los parametros `clabel.col` y `clabel.row` establecen el tamaño de letra, modificando esto lograrías cambiar esta configuración. En cuanto a los margenes, deberías estudiar y modificar [`table.prepare`](https://github.com/cran/ade4/blob/master/R/table.value.R) que en definitiva la que dibuja el gráfico.